# Is anybody else not seeing comments on their iPhone?

Tags: bug

Starting last night I can no longer see comments when using the site on my iPhone, nor can I comment.  Things are fine on my iPad just not my iPhone.  I am wondering if anybody else has ever had this problem or is having this problem.  I presume I accidentally changed some setting but I have no idea how to get commenting back.  I have tried logging back in and out of mathoverflow but it didn't help.  Since I mostly use the site on my phone, this is a bit irksome.

added: Even stranger, I can see comments on other stackexchanges sites.

added: it seems the problem is only in Safari since in Chrome it works.

Comment: What version of iOS do you have (on both devices)?

Comment: @Glorfindel I'm using 14.3 for both

Comment: Right. That's the newest version (it's known that the site doesn't work on very old iOS versions, hence I asked).

Comment: @Glorfindel, I can see comments on the tex and MSE sites.  Just not on mathoverflow and mathoverflow-meta

Comment: Are you using: (a) mobile view; (b) full site in responsive design; (c) full site without responsive design; also important is the phone vertical or horizontal (and rotated view, of course)?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I tried both vertical and horizontal but it didn't make a difference.  I suspect it is mobile view but I never had this issue before and as I said it seems fine on the other stackexchange sites

Comment: @AsafKaragila, how do I turn off mobile view

Comment: Scroll to the bottom of this page, you should see "full site", upon switching you will also see there "disable/enable responsiveness".

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I tried full site and disabled responsiveness and still don't see the comments

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I also don't see the link for add comment

Comment: That is indeed very odd. I don't really know iPhone, but can you use a different browser/disable ad blocking features/try incognito mode?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, if I log out and view the site then I see comments on questions other than my own.  I am not sure how to do incognito mode.  I'll try another browser

Comment: Normally it's in the option, "private browsing" or when you create a new tab.

Comment: @AsafKaragila,  It seems I can see the comments from Chrome on my iphone so I must have done something in safari

Comment: My general suggestion is to ditch Apple altogether. But it might not be a practical one at this point. But it certainly means that the problem is somewhere in your settings. Since I don't use iPhone, I can't quite help you further... :\

Comment: @AsafKaragila,  I guess I'll stick to chrome for MO from now on

Comment: Works fine in my Safari on iPhone.  (Asaf if you want me to give up Apple convince any other phone manufacturer to make a hand-sized phone!  The iPhone mini is literally the only thing in its market!)

Comment: I have the same issue on my iPhone. I use Safari as my browser for almost everything, and use Edge (or the StackOverflow app) for MathOverflow so I can see the comments there. I also find that I can’t see comments on Marginal Revolution in Safari, though I rarely want to.